# Getting "valueError: could not convert string to float: ..." for sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm a beginner trying to learn sklearn pipeline. I get a value error of `ValueError: could not convert string to float` when I run my code below. I'm not sure what's the reason for it since OneHotEncoder shouldn't have any problem converting string to float for categorical variables

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pplonski/datasets-for-start/master/adult/data.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
x_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c!='income']
X = df[x_cols]
y = df['income']
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),['workclass','education','native-country']),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['workclass', 'education', 'marital-status',
                'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex','native-country'])
]
)

clf = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is an issue with scikit-learn's `SimpleImputer` when it tries to impute string variables. Here is a open issue about it on their [github page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19572).

To get around this, I'd recommend splitting up your pipeline into two steps. One for just the replacement of null values and 2) the rest, something like this:

```py
cols_with_null = ['workclass','education','native-country']
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        (
            'imputer', 
            SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent'),
            cols_with_null),
    ])

preprocessor.fit(X_train)
X_train_new = preprocessor.transform(X_train)

for icol, col in enumerate(cols_with_null):
    X_train.loc[:, col] = X_train_new[:, icol]

# confirm no null values in these columns:
for col in cols_with_null:
    print('{}, null values: {}'.format(col, pd.isnull(X_train[col]).sum()))
```

Now that you have `X_train` with no null values, the rest should work without SimpleImputer:

```py
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['workclass', 'education', 'marital-status',
                'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex','native-country'])])

clf = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```